# How to extract TimeGrid Intervals using praat script?

Tags: timecodes

Using praat executable, I can write TextGrid Interval in a text file by clicking on `To TextGrid (vuv)` button in the right panel in the following image. I'm using `To TextGrid (vuv)... 0.02 0.01` code to in the praat script but getting "Command `To TextGrid (vuv)..." not available for current selection` error.

Am I missing something?

Can It be possible to do so using praat script at all?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help.

```
directory$ = "./"
list = Create Strings as file list... list 'directory$'*.wav
numberOfFiles = Get number of strings
if !numberOfFiles
       exit There are no sound files in the folder!
endif

for current_file from 1 to numberOfFiles
       select list
       fileName$ = Get string... current_file
       name$ = fileName$ - ".wav" - ".wav"
       sound = Read from file... 'directory$''fileName$'
       # min and max pitch
       pulses = To PointProcess (periodic, cc)... 30 400
       vuv = To TextGrid (vuv)... 0.02 0.01
       Save as text file... 'directory$''name$'.TextGrid
       plus pulses
       plus sound
       Remove
endfor
```

In addition, you can join [praat-users](http://uk.groups.yahoo.com/group/praat-users/) group on Yahoo where Paul - one of the authors of Praat is very active answering questions. You can learn more about praat scripting on the praat manual here. 
http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Scripting.html